# Save emacs desktop with non-Latin characters

Tags: session, emacs, character-encoding, desktop

I tried to set up the Emacs standard session engine using simple [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/849180/1038377). In general the directories can have Cyrillic names. The problem is the session saved in a wrong coding system. This is the header of `.emacs.desktop`:

`;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; coding: emacs-mule; -*-`

It turned out that exactly this string is hardcoded in `desktop.el`. I also added this into my `~/.emacs` but the coding is still wrong:

```lisp
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq-default coding-system-for-read 'utf-8
              coding-system-for-write 'utf-8
              file-name-coding-system 'utf-8
              default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

I even tried to hardcode utf-8 into the local copy of `desktop.el`, but this doesn't help. Maybe some hooks before the save/load procedure can be used?

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug. See [Reporting Bugs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html#Bugs).

Comment: What @Nick said.

Comment: Reported the bug.

Comment: Was this fixed in https://repo.or.cz/emacs.git?a=commit;h=5bebacc476259f854d3735a6dc5a639016f1673a? Personally, I was facing this in a modern Spacemacs on Emacs 26.2, gave up and switched to using the spacemacs recommended resume-layouts.